# Using something similar to lockable resource in Jenkins on GitLab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, cicd

Our build pipeline involves mainly two stages build and test. During the test stage pipeline communicates with physical microcontroller board. It should not used concurrently by multiple jobs and to preserve this we are using [jenkins lockable resource plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/).
We are now in the middle of transforming these Jenkins jobs to GitLab CICD and did not find any such functionality provided by GitLab. Though not straight forward, the only alternative way we thought we can achieve this was force couple each runner with one test board. It would be great if anyone can share their thoughts if they know how to achieve this in GitLab. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Though not straight forward, the only alternative way we thought we can achieve this was force couple each runner with one test board

This is probably the best approach if your resource (the microcontroller board) may be used across different GitLab projects.

If you only care about resource locking across jobs/pipelines within the *same* GitLab project, you can use [resource groups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#resource_group) to apply locking mechanisms to ensure only one job can acquire the resource lock at any time.

Jobs needing a locked resource will wait for the resource lock to be released (the job holding the lock completes) before they will start. From the docs:

> Use `resource_group` to create a resource group that ensures a job is mutually exclusive across different pipelines for the same project.
>
> For example, if multiple jobs that belong to the same resource group are queued simultaneously, only one of the jobs starts. The other jobs wait until the `resource_group` is free.
>
> Resource groups behave similar to semaphores in other programming languages.
>
> You can define multiple resource groups per environment. For example, when deploying to physical devices, you might have multiple physical devices. Each device can be deployed to, but only one deployment can occur per device at any given time.

Comment: After lot of research we are gonna stick with the way that we are gonna force couple each runner with one test board since we are not locking across jobs/pipelines within same project